# Show for irrational $x$ with a certain condition that for all $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\left|qx-p\right|\ge\frac{1}{200q}$ holds

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

The condition being that there exists a sequence of rational numbers $\frac{p_i}{q_i}$ such that $$\left|x-\frac{p_i}{q_i}\right|<\frac{1}{3q_i^2}$$

And also that $\frac{p_i}{q_i}\ne\frac{p_j}{q_j}$ for all $i\ne{j}$, $p_1<100$ and $0<p_{i+1}<100p_i$.

From a claim in my homework assignment, I can deduce all $\frac{p_i}{q_i}$ appear in $x$'s sequence of convergents.
However I don't know how to proceed. 
Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have made some progress by being able to show that $a_k<100$:

$$a_{k}=\frac{p_{k}-p_{k-2}}{p_{k-1}}<\frac{100p_{k-1}-p_{k-2}}{p_{k-1}}=100-\frac{p_{k-2}}{p_{k-1}}<100$$

Now for any $p,q$, we can take $q_k>q$ and since among all rational approximations, with denominators smaller than a convergent's, we have

$$\left|x-\frac{p_{k}}{q_{k}}\right|<\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|$$
And then since for all $k>0$:

$$\left|x-\frac{p_k}{q_k}\right|>\frac{1}{\left(a_{k+1}+2\right)q_k^2}$$

we get

$$\frac{1}{200q_{k}^{2}}<\frac{1}{\left(a_{k+1}+2\right)q_{k}^{2}}<\left|x-\frac{p_{k}}{q_{k}}\right|<\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|$$

But that doesn't quite get me where I need to be. Is this a good direction? What am I missing?

EDIT: I've found a solution. Thanks for everybody's input.

Comment: I wonder whether the required condition holds for Liouvillie-numbers.

Comment: As stated, it is possible that all $\frac{p_i}{q_i}$ are equal and I am sure the claim is false. Don't you want $p_{i+1}>p_i$?

Comment: More specifically. The condition holds with $x=1+10^{-100}\pi$ and $p_i=q_i=1$ for all $i$, but for $p=q=1$, the claim $|qx-p|\ge \frac1{200q}$ is false.

Comment: You're right, there's a mistake in my stated condition. I'll get some more information about it and edit the question soon. Thank you.

Comment: Edited with clarification. The rationals must be different from one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited with my solution. Slowly but surely I got there. :)

Comment: Having proved that for all algebraic number $x$ it holds $\left|x-\dfrac{p_i}{q_i}\right|\gt\dfrac{C(\epsilon,x)}{q_i^{2+\epsilon}}$ where $C$ is a constant depending only on $x$ and $\epsilon$   was worth Roth the Fields Medal. Your claim is for $x$ irrational so also could be trascendental. Let me say that either your condition is very restrictive or you are wrong.